# Regex to find letter between two numbers python

Tags: python, regex, string

is there a regex to find a letter beween two numbers in a string by using Python ?

**For instance,** given a string like this one "**AAPL1809A170**" I would like to extract **A** only...again, given "**XOM1809C123**" I would like to extract C only...

To solve my problem I just tried this regex: "\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}" but it extract 9A1 or 9C1 given examples strings here above.

Thank you for replying back if possible

Comment: You should be able to use a capture group to extract the letter you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead and positive lookbehind:

```
import re
strings = ["AAPL1809A170", "XOM1809C123"]
final_results = [re.findall('(?<=\d)[A-Z]{1}(?=\d)', s)[0] for s in strings]
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C']
```

Comment: Hey man thanks ! this regex (?<=\d)[A-Z]{1}(?=\d) solved my issue...!

Comment: @AndreaFerrante glad to help!

Comment: `{1}` is an effectively meaningless quantifier.

Comment: @CAustin why ?!

Comment: @AndreaFerrante Because it's the same as simply not writing it. `[A-Z]{1}` matches the same input as `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a capture group to tell the regex engine exactly what you want it to extract from the string - it'll be returned as a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('\d([A-Z])\d', 'XOM1809C123')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f6e597b54e0>
>>> re.search('\d([A-Z])\d', 'XOM1809C123').group(0)
'9C1'
>>> re.search('\d([A-Z])\d', 'XOM1809C123').group(1)
'C'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for replying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `(.*\d)([A-Z])(\d.*)` - This will give you exact ONE Alphabet between numbers.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('(.*\d)([A-Z])(\d.*)', 'XOM1809C123').group(2)
'C'
>>> re.search('(.*\d)([A-Z])(\d.*)', 'AAPL1809A170').group(2)
'A'
```

I find http://rubular.com/ very handy to test regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups to extract what you want from the match:

```
str = 'AAPL1809A170'
match = re.search(r"\d{1}([A-Z])\d{1}", str)
print(match.group(1))
```

The group is whatever you put between parenthesis `()`, e.g., `[A-Z]`, and then you print the group. Since there's only one group specified, `([A-Z])`, use `print(match.group(1))` to print the matched letter. In the case above, this will return `A`.